# Why do I need -CApath for OpenSSL to use my certificates?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm running into an issue where I'm getting an error message:

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

This is my own custom compilation of OpenSSL.  However, my web browser trusts this site just fine.

I've tried going to `<openssldir>/certs/` and putting the certificates in there, then running a little BASH script to make symlinks in the format of `<hash>.0` for each one.  I've read in a few places that this is how it's supposed to work

```
for f in *.pem
do
  ln -s "$f" `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in "$f"`.0
done
```

I'm kinda able to get it working... when I run:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect pypi.python.org:443 -CApath .
```

I get (truncated)

```
Start Time: 1399590981
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

But, when I run:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect pypi.python.org:443
```

I get:

```
Start Time: 1399591046
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Why only when I specify -CApath?

**How can I make it use these by default?**

Comment: You need to add _much_ more details if you want any constructive answer. My wild guess with the little information given right now: you need to specify a ca certificate bundle that allows to verify the servers claim. Note that openssl by itself comes with an _empty_ bundle.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I knew what other details to add...  I have a vanilla OpenSSL installation and I noticed that the 'certs' directory is empty and I tried various things from googling to get certificates installed, though nothing worked.  I found the certificate that's being used on my web browser, and I could export it easily... I thought I could just add it to my openssl installation?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network since its not a programming question. Perhaps Information Security Stack Exchange (http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this command, you verify the company the certificate comes from:

```
openssl s_client -connect pypi.python.org:443
```

Result:

```
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

You don't have the root certificate for it... then you download DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.crt  from:
https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm

And use it with `-CAfile`:

```
openssl s_client -connect pypi.python.org:443 -CAfile DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.crt
```

Now it works!

Comment: That's great!  Thanks, that does clarify a lot.  How do I make OpenSSL use this by default?

Comment: it depends on your scenario... http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml

Comment: @Scott - "... how do I make OpenSSL use this by default?" - OpenSSL's security model *is* different than the browser security model. By default, OpenSSL trusts nothing. You have to explicitly specify what to trust when using OpenSSL. That's in contrast to the browsers, which trust nearly everything by default.

Comment: oh sorry, now I see what you mean... you can use what's called a "CA bundle"... I use this one from cURL: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html Download the cacert.pem and use it instead of DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.crt. So your OpenSSL is gonna be able to recognize everything... it's the samething as download many root certificates from many companies and put in a single file!v ;-)